# Adding items through navigation and storing in new context

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am getting started with EF4 and struggle to understand how I should add objects correctly.
It is a multitier application where I have a datalayer, which returns my entity. I then in a business layer alter that entity and add objects to its linked objects through navigation. However I seem to run into a problem, when I try to update the entity, when related objects have been added.

So I have something like this:

FirstTypeOfObject: Id, SomeProperty
SecondTypeOfObject: Id, SomeProperty, FKToFirstTypeOfObject
ThirdTypeOfObject: Id, SomeProperty, FKToSecondTypeOfObject

So I have a 1 to many to many relationship.

Now in my DAL I retrieve a FirstTypeOfObject:

```
using(var context = new ObjectContext())
{
  var first = context.FirstTypeOfObjects
    .Single(i => i.id = "something")
    .Include(o => o.SecondTypeOfObjects.Select(s => s.ThirdKindOfObjects))) 
  return first;
}
```

I then in my businesslayer add to this object:

```
ThirdKindOfObject t = new ThirdKindOfObject();
t.SomeProperty = "test";
t.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
first.SecondTypeOfObjects.FirstOrDefault().Add(t);
```

I then call a method in my DAL:

```
public void UpdateObject(FirstTypeOfObject myObject)
{
  using(var context = new ObjectContext())
  {
    context.FirstTypeOfObject.Attach(myObject)
    context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myObject, EntityState.Modified);
    context.SaveChanges()
  }
}
```

But when I update the item I get an error:

```
An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context
```

I don't want to go to the database everytime I need to create a ThirdTypeOfObject, as it might be 100s of objects. Also I would like to pass the entity model around for modification and my DAL doesn't know what have been modified. I don't want my DAL to know of any classes written in the business layer.

Am I doing this as it wasn't intended? Am I just missing out on something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also I would like to pass the entity model around for modification and my DAL doesn't know what have been modified. I don't want my DAL to know of any classes written in the business layer.
>
> Am I doing this as it wasn't intended? Am I just missing out on something?

Instead of micro managing the database context, i.e. opening and closing a new context in every method of the DAL layer, you should use one database context per HTTP request. The database context would then track all changes within a given HTTP request. The ObjectContext is actually an implementation of [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) and using a [dependency injection container](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) you could set the lifetime of the unit of work to the scope of a HTTP request. This would eliminate disconnected entities, which can be troublesome as you've found out.

Depending on your architecture, you'd want to save changes to the context in a layer above the business layer.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Using AutoFac DI I now create an objectContext per HttpRequest and that works for me. My DAL now returns the entity. It is then modified by the higher layers, and then changes are saved by calling a method in the DAL which then calls .SaveChanges()